# Changes needs to be reflected before the NIB loads in WindowController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to load the nib file of my windowController.

I am calling the windowController class from AppDelegate

```
-(IBAction)test:id(sender)
{
//Loading the WindowController Class

   Test1 *wc = [[Test1 alloc]init]alloc];

   [wc showWindow:self];

/*Some code Changes done*/

/*Changes done to add value to the text Field of the Window Controller*/
}
```

There are few changes made to get the value of the Window Controller XIB,

In the Test1Class, the values is retrieved using:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{

//Code added to retrieve the Text Field data

}
```

But when the window launches the changes made is not getting reflected.

But when putting the breakpoints, the value is getting set but is not getting to show on the TextField, But in XIB IBOutlet has been connected for the NSTextField, for the IBoutlet value is not getting set.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you be more specific ? if I have understood, you want to update the view controller 1 from the view controller 2 ?

Comment: Actually i am setting the value in Appdelegate and trying to set it to the Window. I am writting the code in WindowControllerClass

Answer (score 0):

Is the IBOutlet pointer nil when you are trying to set it?

awakeFromNib: is a better place than init to do what I think you're trying to do.  Outlets are fairly likely to be nil during init, and you'll get no warning doing an assignment to them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i am doing my changes in WindowController, can i do it with awakeFromNib? As of now the IBOutlet is pointing to nil.

Comment: awakeFromNib is called after outlets become non-nil, so yes.  That's why I made it an answer and not a comment.

Comment: You should accept answers for your five questions.  It is the polite thing to do if they are correct/helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @stevisla: Still working on the issue and it is not getting fixed!!!Anyways thanks for ur answer