# XIB of the WindowController Class not loading with the value set in AppDelegate class

Tags: objective-c, xib, appdelegate

In my `AppDelegate` method i am setting the value for the Text Field of a `WindowController` Class.

```
/*IBAction in my AppDelegate*/
-(IBAction)test:id(sender)
{

Test1 *wc = [[Test1 alloc]init]alloc]; //Loading the Window Controller Class//
 [wc showWindow:self];

/*Changes done to add values for the Text Field*/
```

In my Test1 Window Controller Class in `initWithWindow` method i am setting the value for the Text Field.

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{

/*Code Added to set the value*/

}
```

In the `XIB` of the `WindowController` class, an `IBOutlet` has been connected.

But when Window gets launched, the value for the text Field is not getting set, but while putting the break points, i can see the value being set to the `IBoutlet` but not to be seen in The UI.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866501/changes-needs-to-be-reflected-before-the-nib-loads-in-windowcontroller

Answer (score 1):

IBOutlets will get instantiated only after the nib is loaded. Hence any changes you wish to make should be in awakeFromNib or in windowDidLoad.

So your code for Test1 Window Controller Class  now should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{

    //Some piece of code.. 
    //Don't set the text field's value here

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    /*Code Added to set the value*/
}
```

Note that you don't invoke windowDidLoad by yourself. It is invoked automatically when the window is shown.

Comment: In WindowController Class can we add awakeFromNib?

Comment: Yes..  you can.. or add it in windowDidLoad

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, even adding the code in windowDidLoad, not able to set the value, it is showing as NULL only for that IBOutLet

Comment: Sure that the IBOutlet connected??

Comment: yeah its connected, but now when i put break points and check, i get the IBOutlet as NULL, hence may be it is not getting set to the UI.

Comment: if IBOutlet is NULL in windowDidLoad, then most probably it is not properly set. Try clean build

Comment: Clean build is also done!!..If we see the code,IBAction test, i am loading Test1 *wc = [[Test1 alloc]init]alloc];.Therefore in the -(id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window method i am doing the following:-(id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window { /*Some Piece of Code /*[self windowDidLoad];, in WindowDidLoad the Value is set for the IBOutlet, is the approach correct?

Comment: why are you calling [self windowDidLoad] in your init? You should not do it.. When the window loads, this method is automatically invoked

Comment: Even by setting the value there is not working!!! Just a simple setStringvalue like [tID setStringvalue:@"Hi"];, even this line in windowDidLoad is not working!!!!! *Here tId is my outlet, the value is not going and sitting

Comment: Are you called  [self windowDidLoad]  in initWithWindow: ?? If so it is wrong

Comment: No i have removed the line of code...the initWithWindow has only return self now, nothing else

Comment: Try allocating your controller using initWithNibName:

Comment: i just noticed.. you have written [[Test1 alloc]init]alloc];

Comment: There is an extra aloc after init.. Remove it.. and check now

Comment: Hi, that was actually a typo i made by mistake!!! i have not written 2 alloc in the statement

Comment: And i hope you have written alloc init.. and not init alloc, as shown in your question. ok initialise using initWithNibName: and pass the correct nib name and check

Comment: The problem is how ever the value is not getting set to the label and it is showing as NIL only...!!